# Architecture for integration-testing a web extension with a web-server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, google-chrome-extension, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I have a web extension whose functionality needs to be tested against a web server. The web extension is built using Webpack and should run on Chrome and Firefox. It has its own unit tests, but what's important is that we perform behavioral tests against the web server.

The web server currently is a Docker Compose project consisting of a Rails web server (whose port 3000 is exposed to the localhost) and an internal Postgres database.

Currently, we perform testing a little bit manually: we build the extension code into Chrome/Firefox source code, load that code into Chrome, and call an extension-internal function that performs various actions. We then check on the server that everything was received as expected.

[image]

We'd like to turn this into a more automated process, particularly with the aim of testing new branches of client and/or server against each other. Ideally, this process should run in a CI pipeline (GitLab CI) whenever a new branch of client and/or server is being pushed.

We thought about the following setup:

- There will be a new integration testing repository containing a Selenium hub and Chrome/Firefox instance
- That repository will pull the respective client/server code to be tested from a specified branch
- There is a Selenium test script that executes the required tests
- The server is run natively inside the test environment, and not via Docker Compose

[image]

The reason for doing this is that the server currently runs in a Docker Compose project. My thinking is that I should not run that alongside yet another Docker Compose Selenium project. Hence the idea to build it natively. But then again, that means requiring an extra build process.

So another variant could look like this:

[image]

Here, I'd run the server as-is as a Docker Compose project, run Selenium inside another Docker Compose project, both within the same testing environment. The client would communicate with the server via the localhost.

I specifically do not want to put this functionality into the client alone, or the server alone, which is why I thought about a separate repository.

To me, variant 2 seems more reasonable, but perhaps I am missing something obvious, and there could be an even simpler solution?

To make the questions more concrete:

1. Does it make sense to put this functionality into an extra repository?
2. Is there a simpler approach to running the server code from this extra repository?
3. How would one define which version of client/server is being tested at any given time? Would I use this testing repository within the CI pipeline of both server and client, and always checkout the master of the respective other component to test against?

Comment: Alternative 2 sounds a lot more sane to me.